# Strange Crash on Download of iPhone App -- Deleting it and redownloading fixed it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store

I have an iPhone app which works great most of the time, but one time when I downloaded it from the AppStore, I continually got the below error. This error continued until I deleted and reinstalled the application. Note that it did not run correct even once before starting this crash, and this crash happened almost at the exact time I touched the icon. Its strange, because it would not even have time to change any configuration files. Also, as you can see the crash occurred outside of my code. Any information would be appreciated.

```
Incident Identifier: F1333682-4BC7-44D7-9D7F-485EB7875780
CrashReporter Key:   657dffd01725b5b4b119912904a52134bc517824
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         iGunPro [9297]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/A97E28F0-A0A1-45A2-A966-8EB0DC359945/iGunPro.app/iGunPro
Identifier:      iGunPro
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-12-02 02:26:34.590 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3744532c 0x37434000 + 70444
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3635cf54 0x3630f000 + 319316
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36355fe4 0x3630f000 + 290788
3   GraphicsServices                0x321c6444 0x321c2000 + 17476
4   GraphicsServices                0x321c6e84 0x321c2000 + 20100
5   UIKit                           0x36fc6520 0x36f95000 + 202016
6   iGunPro                         0x00006d20 main (main.m:53)
7   iGunPro                         0x0000374c start + 44

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x374353b4 0x37434000 + 5044
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36697e78 0x3668b000 + 52856
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36697b96 0x3668b000 + 52118

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37445cd4 0x37434000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3631930a 0x3630f000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3631909c 0x3630f000 + 41116

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37445cd4 0x37434000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3631930a 0x3630f000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3631909c 0x3630f000 + 41116

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37435010 0x37434000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37435206 0x37434000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33dee41c 0x33d61000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33ded154 0x33d61000 + 573780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33d704d6 0x33d61000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33d7039e 0x33d61000 + 62366
6   WebCore                         0x3483f128 0x34797000 + 688424
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3631ec16 0x3630f000 + 64534
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3631ead0 0x3630f000 + 64208

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3f37ece8      r6: 0x3f52ffe0      r7: 0x2fdffc84
    r8: 0x2fdffd60    r9: 0x00272000     r10: 0x00000001     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdffc78      lr: 0x3635cf5b      pc: 0x3744532c
  cpsr: 0x00000010`
`
```

Comment: Can you post a symbolicated version of this crash?

Comment: Are you making any calls for graphic in very early stage of application start up? such as in applicationDidFinishLaunching??

Comment: @pho0 - This is symbolicated. Notice the main (main.m:53) with the line number included. To my knowlage, its not possible to symbolicate iOS functions.

Comment: It is absolutely possible to symbolicate iOS functions, you just won't get line numbers which wouldn't help anyway. But you get the class and methods. To do that, that you need the symbols of the corresponding iOS version on your mac and the full crash report with the binary images section. But this looks rather like a bug in iOS than in your app.

Comment: Did you try the old standby -- powering off and back on?  (Though I'm guessing that something got fouled up in the app configuration.)  (BTW, what's at main:53 in your code?)

Comment: @HotLicks - No, I'm regretting not resetting it before reinstalling, but regardless, a clean install needs to work right or I'm going to lose users.

Comment: @HotLicks - To answer your second question, its simply
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

Comment: @Kemi - I wonder why Organizer did not symbolicate then? Maybe its not possible when grabbing it directly off my device, but will come with the error reports later?

Comment: The *very first* time it started up after installing, did it seem to get any further than subsequent attempts?  Do you have a splash screen?  Did it display at all?  Were all the crash reports identical?

Comment: @HotLicks - I downloaded it, and tried to open it 4 times. All 4 crash reports were identical. After this, I deleted it and re-downloaded it and it was fine. My fear is that a % of my users are not using the app due to this.

Comment: You don't have a splash?

Answer (score 0):

This looks as though there is some process running in a background thread that shouldn't.  For example, if you attempted some sort of UI manipulation using grand central dispatch that is NOT on the main queue, you might see this behavior. Another example, if you are using core data and you are sharing a managed object context across threads, you may see this behavior.

Something else to consider, there is probably a variable that is being overreleased.

Comment: Its still strange that it would not work until a reinstall though. Also, I don't think this looks like an over-release, but I could be wrong. Its happening almost immediately and as you can tell by the trace, it looks like it crashed before I even hit any of my code. I was thinking it perhaps was related to something I linked against.